# Finding in which vector does the element belong to

Tags: r

suppose I have 3 vectors:

```
a = c("A", "B", "C")
b = c("D", "E", "F")
c = c("G", "H", "I")
```

then I have an element:

```
element = "E"
```

I want to find which list does my element belongs to. In this case, list b.

It will be appreciated if the solution to this problem is more general because my real data set have more than a hundred lists.

Comment: FYI those are vectors, not lists

Comment: @Sotos title and text now confusingly refer to lists and vectors...

Comment: @jay.sf better?

Comment: @Sotos I don't know, it's rather unclear what OP actually wants.

Comment: @jay.sf well that's a different story. Title and text now are the same. This is the best I can do. I cannot read OP mind to know exactly what they want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element = "E"
names(our_lists)[sapply(our_lists, `%in%`, x = element)]
# [1] "b"
```

Data

```
our_lists <- list(
  a = c("A", "B", "C"),
  b = c("D", "E", "F"),
  c = c("G", "H", "I")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep`.

```
element <- "E"
l <- mget(c("a", "b", "c"))
names(l)[grep(element, l)]
# [1] "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the data in individual objects, you need to check for the `element` in each one individually. Get them in a list.

```
list_data <- mget(c('a', 'b', 'c'))
names(Filter(any, lapply(list_data, `==`, element)))
#[1] "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your vectors have the same length then a vectorised idea can be,

```
c('a', 'b', 'c')[ceiling(which(c(a, b, c) == 'E') / length(a))]
#[1] "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::lst` that creates named list from variable names. Then `purrr::keep` to keep only the vectors that contain your element.

```
require(tidyverse)
lst(a, b, c) %>% 
  keep(~ element %in% .x) %>% 
  names()
```

output:

```
[1] "b"
```